# ASP.NET MVC Detail grid indention

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How would I indent the detail grid of a row using Telerik UI ASP.NET MVC?  The examples given are very basic.  I'm beginning to doubt if it is even possible

In the attached image I'd like for the edge at the red arrow to be indented to match the red line.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a style rule like:

```
.k-detail-row > .k-detail-cell {
    padding-left: 450px; /* This gets it to about where the red line is in the screen shot. */
}
```

and set the value to whatever you find appropriate.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/EsEDo